# linq query conditions by database and a list contents

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception, linq-to-entities

I want to retrieve all tickets whose badge number is present in the list

i have a listA

public class Li

```
     {
         public string s { get; set; }
         public string t { get; set; }
         public string b { get; set; }
   }
```

i have a method
i try this condition but it doesn't work,

doesn't recognize tostring for the first and doesn't recognize the list

Any idea how solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`where listeLigneXls.Select(lgn => lgn.badge).Contains(chb.NUM_BADGE)`

Comment: Look the article, it can be useful for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Need to change in this code block

```
        where listeLigneXls.Select(lgn =>lgn.badge).Contains(chb.NUM_BADGE)
```

Contain is extension method of list of primitive data type

Comment: exactly , When I try the query an exception is up telling me "can not create a constant value only primitive are supported " what i need to change ?

Comment: What is the type of this chb.NUM_BADGE list is.

Comment: NUM_BADGE is a string

Comment: can you resend the code after what you make changes

Answer (score 0):

I change the method I get the values of the badge number and I would like to use it in my second query but I do not know how